# Query Object's elements in c#

Tags: c#, linq, object, iqueryable, objectquery

I have a problem when i try to retrieve query results from object in c#.

I did a linq query that return object element and the i wanna get all elements value in c# (server side)...

I can't do this and i don't know why!

I tried:

```
forech(var x in element)
{
  string titolo= x.title.ToString();
}
```

and

```
dynamic temp=(dynamic)element;

string titolo=temp.title.ToString();
```

AND OTHERS....

I can see that the object type is:

```
{
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<<>f__AnonymousType26<int,string,string,bool?,int?,System.Linq.IQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType25<string>>>>
}
```

How can i get object's values?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you heard the saying "A picture is worth a thousand words?" The same applies to code.

Comment: Can you post a little of your code that you're having trouble with? I'm not entirely sure how to help structure a answer without some context.

Comment: Enrico, ci faresti vedere la LINQ query per piacere?

Comment: Of what type is "element"?
You might have to enumerate `element.Items` or `element.Controls` or the like.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the properties attached to the element, you could do something like this:

```
 foreach(var item in element)
 {
     foreach(var property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
     {
          // property.Name = Name of property.
          // property.GetValue(element, null) - Gets the value of the property (as System,Object).
     }
 }
```

Comment: Tejs, your code works apart the "property.GetValue(element,null)" that should be return an object, but for me doesn't work...

Comment: Ok, i've corrected the GetValue() method that it will be:         
object value= property.GetValue(item,null);

NOW I SOLVED MY PROBLEM! THANKS TO ALL!